# How to get products with the same custom attribute like ean code

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, custom-field, meta-query

I Try to get all products with the same ean code, but the query doesn't work and also doesn't give any errors. What am I missing?
Here is the code I use.

```
if (is_product()) {
    global $product;
    $ean = $product->get_attribute('EAN');

    // Build query
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_type'      => 'NUMERIC',
        'meta_key'       => '_price',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
        'tax_query'      => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'ean',
                'field'    => 'name',
                'terms'    => explode(',', $ean),
                'operator' => 'IN',
            ),
        ),
    ));
    
    if ($query->have_posts() && $query->found_posts > 0) {
        var_dump($product);
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } 
    else {
      echo 'No related products found.';
    }
    // Output the final query
    echo $query->request;
    // Check for query errors
    if ($query->is_main_query() && $query->is_tax() && empty($query->posts)) {
       echo 'Query error: ' . $query->get('error');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to list products with post_type=product etc.. AND have the same ean code. Therefore, in your place i would try with the line
`'relation' => 'OR'`
changed to
`'relation' => 'AND'`

Regards,

Comment: `post_type` is separate from the `tax_query`, and the `relation` here is part of the `tax_query`; they've only got one item in the `tax_query` so the `relation` is probably unnecessary.

Comment: exactly, the relation here is unnecessary. But I see when I remove the tax_query, that I get 890 results back

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. To query products apparently you shouldn't use WP_Query(), but instead use wc_get_products(). By doing this I am able to query products and get results. More info can be found here: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query#wc_product_query-methods